# Cheapest way to travel in Amsterdam and nearby

Tags: public-transport, netherlands, amsterdam, rotterdam, the-hague

I am going to Amsterdam for 10 days. I plan to stay at Haarlem and travel to Amsterdam Central daily. Also I have planed day trips to Rotterdam and The Hague. Is there any travel pass that will take care of the above travel arrangements? Also I will be using public transportation within Amsterdam.

Comment: Some more information is required. How old are you? Are you traveling alone or with a group of people? Is car rental an option? Do you consider using a bike? During what days do you travel the most, during weekends, before 10h00?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider buying an [OV-chipkaart](https://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/home-1.htm#/). With this, you can board any train, metro, or bus in almost the entire country and pay per kilometer of travel. It costs €7.50, however every time you have to buy a paper ticket for the NS train you pay €1 extra. Since you'll be buying around 20 paper tickets (Haarlem to Amsterdam/Rotterdam/The Hague and back for 10 days), it should save you a few bucks. Plus, if you come back in the next 5 years, you can use it again!

If you're planning on use the metro inside Amsterdam extensively, you can also consider getting a [1 to 7 day unlimited pass](https://en.gvb.nl/gvb-dag-meerdagenkaart). This can be loaded onto an OV-chipkaart or used as a paper ticket. It only works on buses and trams inside Amsterdam though, so you'll still have to get an NS paper ticket or use the stored value on your OV-chipkaart to get into Amsterdam from Haarlem.